# Can't use protocol with generic type already defined

Tags: swift

I can't seem to understand why I am getting this error if I already defined that `T` is of type `String` in `SomeUseCaseProtocol`. Is there any workaround to do this?

```
protocol UseCase {
    associatedtype T
    func execute(params: T)
}

protocol SomeUseCaseProtocol: UseCase where T == String { }

class SomeClass {
    init(someUseCase: SomeUseCaseProtocol) { // <-- ERROR: Protocol SomeUseCaseProtocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just not something that Swift supports at the moment. Here's an issue that's still unresolved: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4758

Comment: `init<T: SomeUseCaseProtocol>(someUseCase: T) {`